# Unable to change home folder setting in Samba/Winbind

Tags: samba, home, active-directory, winbind

I'm using a Debian 8 server at work. Recently, I used Samba and Winbind to join it to the domain. This domain is managed by Active Directory on a Windows Server machine. This all works: domain users can SSH into the server with their AD passwords, `wbinfo` gives me domain groups or users, and so on. I even get domain groups when I use the "groups" command on local Debian users who also have domain accounts.

Here's the problem. When I set all this up, I thought I wanted to put all newcomers to the server in `/home/domain/username`, so I set up my `smb.conf` file accordingly. Now, though, I've changed my mind thanks to an Nginx setup I won't go into here. I want users to go to `/home/username` instead. I've updated `smb.conf`, but my new setting won't take effect.

The first user I've been testing all this on is me, but I'm an admin for the domain. I needed a non-admin user, so chose someone who works just down the hall. She logged in before I made the change, and, as you'd expect, was given a `/home/domain/username` folder. Now that I've decided not to use the domain folder for home directories, though, I want to move her home folder to `/home/username`. The Nginx thing makes it important that this happens. I also want this to happen for all future users who get on the server, but everyone is currently stuck in `/home/domain/username` instead.

I've so far tried `usermod`, but that fails because, as a domain user, this test user is not in the local system at all, so there's no entry in `/etc/passwd`. I've tried username, `domain\\username`, `domain\\\\username`, and other variants. My winbind separator is indeed backslash. I knew none of this would work, since `passwd` has no record of this user at all, but I tried just the same.

I've also tried moving the user's home folder where I want it, so her old folder is gone, then having her log in. I hoped Samba would find no home folder, see my new template telling it where to place users, and go to `/home/username`. Instead, it created `/home/domain/username` again, and put her in there. I'm having her log in over SSH.

When I run

```
getent passwd
```

I get all the domain users and groups, but all of them show home folders of `/home/domain/username` instead of `/home/username`. Yet, in `smb.conf`, I have this in the [globals] section:

```
template homedir = /home/%U
```

I've restarted Samba several times. I've even made these changes to sssd and restarted that, although I'm not using sssd. I restarted ssh just to be sure. I now know why my test user won't move, but that only showed me that all users will have this problem. Indeed, when I had a second user log in over SSH using domain credentials, she, too, went to `/home/domain/username`.

Nothing has worked so far. I don't know what else I should try in order to get the home folder setting how I want it. Can anyone spot anything I might have missed: a setting, something to restart, anything? I'm new to using Linux on a domain, so have cobbled my current setup together from many online articles and forums. It works, but I don't know enough about it to troubleshoot extensively. If I've missed telling you any important details, let me know.

Comment: The AD server has no home folders specified for any users. On the off chance that this would help, I looked yesterday before I posted the question. That said, I'm by no means an AD expert. Is there anywhere else that a home folder might be specified, apart from the properties of the profile in question? Again, too, I'm trying to change the home folder in Debian when the user SSH-es in, not the home folder the user would go to on a Windows box when logging in with AD credentials. I don't know whether these are the same in AD.

Comment: I have absolutely no clue... I'm neither good with samba neither with AD

Comment: Why do you have `winbind` and `sssd` installed at the same time? If you're not using `sssd` I would really recommend you get rid of it. (But better, would be to use `sssd` and move on from `winbind`. Really.)

Comment: I have both because some articles used one, some used the other. I tried SSSD first, and could never get it to work. When I instead switched to Winbind, everything went quite smoothly. I'm now nervous about removing SSSD, for fear of knocking down the house of cards I've somehow managed to get working. :) Why do you suggest SSSD over Winbind? I have no preference, except Winbind seemed to work more easily, so I went with it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out. It's probably obvious to any Linux admins, but it's new to me.

The changes I made are in /etc/samba/smb.conf. Restarting Samba, I thought, would apply those changes to anything that needed to know about them. After all, restarting Samba restarts four packages total. In reality, I also had to restart winbind on its own. As soon as I did that, it picked up the updated smb.conf and everything worked as I wanted it to. Lesson: if you use winbind with Samba, restart both of them.